# Node.js, request, How to close proper way an upload readable stream before end

Tags: node.js, upload, request, resume, cancellation

I'm writing a `CLI` script to a resumable upload file stream.
When I click `CTRL-C` save current state before exit.
Problem is I don't know how to cancel upload stream proper way with request.js.

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
stream.pipe(request.put(options, callback));
```